# Shellscript Convert CSV to XML

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

Here I have a requirement to display based on the availability same segment should repeat. How to get array comparison?

I have a CSV file like the below:-

### Column [0], Column [1]

```
AE1110,922222222
AE2220,911222222
AE2220,9332222
AT300314,944422222
AT300314,955511111
```

and I want to convert to XML like this:

```
<xml>
<Header>
<Filename>AE_AAA_20190312211427.xml</Filename>
</Header>
<Record>
<AVAILABILITY>922222222</AVAILABILITY>
<AAADATE>2019-03-07</AAADATE>
</Record>
<Footer>
<TotalNoOfRecords>1</TotalNoOfRecords>
</Footer>
</xml>
```

Based on the number of Availbility Total No of Records should compute. Here I need to print same segement twice if I have 2 availiability.

```
#!/bin/bash
file_in="sample.csv"
now="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
tstamp=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
while IFS=$',' read -r -a arry
do
country_code=$(echo "${arry[0]}" | awk '{print substr ($0, 0, 2)}')
filename=${country_code}_"ARRW"_$tstamp
file_out="${filename}".xml
for i in `${arry[0]}|awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}{if (++dup[$1] >= 2) print}'`;
do
echo $i
done
echo '<xml>
<Header>' > $file_out
echo '    <Filename>'${filename}'</Filename>' >> $file_out
echo '  <Record>' >> $file_out
echo '    <AVAILABILITY>'${arry[1]}'</AVAILABILITY>' >> $file_out
echo '    <AAADATE>'${now}'</AAADATE>' >> $file_out
echo '  </Record>' >> $file_out
echo '</Footer>
</xml>' >> $file_out
done < $file_in
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for **that** sample input to your question.

Comment: input is the csv file i mentioned and output is the xml i mentioned.

Comment: @goldeneagle : I don't understand the question. In the sample you provided, I don't see anything printed twice.

Comment: Sorry for any miscommunication, Here is my  doubt, I want to reiterate the loop if column[0] is duplicated. Presently it is not reiterating.

Comment: Your question needs much more detailed input and output examples. The only commonalty between the input and output you have shown are `AE`, `AT`, and `922222222`. What is the definition of `segment`?